# Similar results on Real Analysis by J.Yeh?

Tags: real-analysis

These are two results of the text real analysis by J. Yeh

**Proposition 13.11**. *If f is a real-valued function which is both absolutely countinuous and singular on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$.*

**Lemma 13.16** *Let $f$ be an absolutely continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$, if $f'=0$ a.e. on $[a,b]$ the $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$.*

The first is proved by the some estimates the second by the Vitali Covering Lemma.

For me these results say the same thing, or not? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed. Although in your version Lemma $13.16$ is completely different in the second line: "the $f$ is constant", whereas in Lemma $13.11$ it only says :"then $f$ is constant". The latter sounds better.